# Is there Any Homomorphism Between Vector Spaces that is not Linear?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples, group-homomorphism

I am learning Abstract Algebra and professor asked the existence of group homomorphism between vector spaces that is not linear.

I think there would be one which artificially constructed since the linearity given in vector space seems independent from the property of group homomorphism.

Any example of those non-linear group homomorphism between vector spaces?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb C$ as a complex vector space in the usual sense. Then the conjugation is a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{C},+)$ into itself which is not linear: $\overline{i.1}\neq i.\overline1$.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps your professor is referring to a morphism between two vector spaces such that:

$$f( a + b) = f(a) \oplus f(b)$$
But it happens that:
$$
\lambda f(a) \neq f(\lambda a)
$$

It turns out that such functions do exist. The best example of whose existence can be proved (but cannot be constructed) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Existence_of_nonlinear_solutions_over_the_real_numbers).

Comment: what do you mean could not be constructed but exist???

Comment: @delinco Structures whose explicit construction would decide an undecidable statement can't be explicitly constructed, even if the axioms imply they exist. A famous example: given any set $S$, there is an ordinal $\alpha$ for which an $S\to\alpha$ bijection exists. However, the case $S=\mathbb{R}$ prevents us constructing one because it would either prove or disprove the continuum hypothesis. rubikscube09 is discussing an example where the undecidability of the axiom of choice is the problem.

Comment: I think this answer should include some mention of the field. Over the rational numbers, such functions do not exist.