# For a given $f \in \text{Hom}(V,W)$ there exist bases $B$ and $C$ of $V$ and $W$ such that $M_C^B(f) = \begin{bmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $f \in \text{Hom}(V,W)$ is a homomorphism with $\text{rank}(f) = r.$

Prove that there exist bases $B$ and $C$ of $V$ and $W$, respectively, such that
$$M_C^B(f) = \begin{bmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
where $I_r$ is an $r \times r$ identity matrix.

My attempt: Let $\{u_1, \dots, u_{n-r}\}$ be a basis of $\text{Ker}(f)$ (where $n$ denotes $\text{dim}V$) and add $r$ vectors $\{v_1, \dots, v_r\}$ to form the base for $V$. Denote
$$B = \{u_1^*, \dots, u_n^*\} = \{v_1, \dots, v_r, u_1, \dots, u_{n-r}\}.$$
I thought that this would get me somewhere, but I can't seem to obtain $C$ with this idea.

Another approach: If $\{u_1, \dots, u_n\}$ is some basis for $V$, then there exist $\{u_{i_1}, \dots, u_{i_r}\} \subseteq \{u_1, \dots, u_n\}$ such that $\{f(u_{i_1}), \dots, f(u_{i_r})\}$ is a linear independent set. Renumerate the basis,
$$B = \{u_{i_1}, \dots, u_{i_r}, u_{i_{r+1}}, \dots, u_{i_n}\}$$
where the ordering of last $n-r$ vectors is not important. Then I've managed to get the first part of $C$ and not the second part. Should I choose specific $u_{i_{r+1}}, \dots, u_{i_n}$?

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach will work:

The key is that by construction $(f(v_1),\dots,f(v_r))$ are linearly independent. (Prove it.)

So, $B=(v_1,\dots,v_r,u_1,\dots,u_{n-r})$ is a basis of $V$ with $(u_1,\dots,u_{n-r})$ being a basis of $\ker f$.

And let $C$ be any extension of $(f(v_1),\dots,f(v_r))$ to a basis of $W$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass that's what bothered me in the first place. I couldn't prove that statement; I got stuck with some coefficients and I hoped to use the property of $f$ being a homomorphism. Could you provide any hints for proving that?

Comment: Hint: if $\sum_i\lambda_i f(v_i)=0$ then $\sum_i\lambda_iv_i\in\ker f={\rm span}(u_1,\dots,u_{n-r})$.

Comment: @Berci I thought about that, but I'm not sure that every homomorphism is linear. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, homomorphism means linear here.

Comment: What about this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742587/is-there-any-homomorphism-between-vector-spaces-that-is-not-linear

Comment: @mathbbandstuff The question you linked to is about  **group** homomorphisms, which are defined as preserving the group operation (in this case $+$). But **vector space** homomorphisms are defined as preserving the vector space operations, i.e., not only $+$ but also multiplication by scalars. So vector space homomorphisms are, as Berci said, linear.

Comment: @AndreasBlass oh, I get it now. Thank you all very much!