# Is every additive map $\mathbb{F}_q^n\to \mathbb{F}_q^m$ also a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-transformations, finite-fields

Consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, and consider a map $f:\mathbb{F}_q^n\to\mathbb{F}_q^m$ such that $f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = f(\mathbf{x}) + f(\mathbf{y})$. Is this map automatically a linear transformation? [This does not hold if the field is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742587/is-there-any-homomorphism-between-vector-spaces-that-is-not-linear), so I'm wondering what happens when the field is finite.

To prove that $f$ is a linear transformation we'd need to show that $f(c\cdot\mathbf{x}) = c\cdot f(\mathbf{x})$ for every $c\in\mathbb{F}_q$. If $q = p$ for some prime $p$, then this holds from the additive property directly, since $c\cdot\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x} + \cdots + \mathbf{x}$, $c$ times. However, if $q = p^k$ for some $k>1$, then this is not true anymore since $c$ is not just an "integer". However, I'm wondering if we can still somehow leverage the additive property even in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear functions from $\mathbb{F}_q$ to $\mathbb{F}_q$ are described by $x\mapsto cx$ where $c\in\mathbb{F}_q$.

The number of such functions is $q$.

But for $q=p^n$ where $n>1$,

the number of $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear functions from $\mathbb{F}_q$ to $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $p^{n\times n}=q^n$.

This is because $\mathbb{F}_q$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. But these $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear functions are all additive.

$\\$

**Exercise**: apply a similar argument to additive functions $f:\mathbb{F}_q^n\to\mathbb{F}_q^m$.

Comment: Thanks. I get what you are saying, but I don't get exactly what this implies for my question. I do get that there are $q^2$ $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear mappings $\mathbb{F}_q\to\mathbb{F}_q$, and this is regardless of whether $p$ is a prime or not, actually. I also get that, of course, all of these are additive. What I'm not getting is how this sheds some light in whether all additive mappings $\mathbb{F}_q\to\mathbb{F}_q$ are included there.

Comment: Wait, I think I can see the point here. There are $q^2$ additive functions $\mathbb{F}_q\to\mathbb{F}_q$, but there are only $q$ $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear mappings $\mathbb{F}_q\to\mathbb{F}_q$. This shows that not every additive mapping is $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear. Thanks!

Comment: BTW I think it should be $p^{n\cdot n} = q^n$, not $q^2$.

Comment: Ah yes, will correct it